# How to send objects with arrays using angular resource?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have a product object with a property called `category_ids` that is an array of ids.

I've added an `$update`  method to my resource factory so I can send a PUT request.

When I PUT, the server receives data that looks like:

```
id: 1,
description: 'Yada yada',
category_ids: [1,2,3],
product: { id: 1, description: 'Yada yada' } //<-- I need category_ids in here
```

How can I get the `category_ids` array into the `product` node there?

---

**More detail:**

I'm just using angular's resource to update:

```
'use strict'

angular.module('myApp').factory 'Product', ($resource) ->

  resource = $resource '/api/v1/products/:id', { id: '@id' },
    update:
      method: 'PUT'

  return resource
```

---

Interestingly, this problem only happens with calling instance methods on my object. Calling the class methods on the factory itself works:

`currentProduct.$update()` <-- This does not give me the format I want!

`Product.update(id: currentProduct.id, product: currentProduct)` <-- This does :-\

Comment: Can you show how you are posting the data to the server now?

Comment: Sure, just added some more detail

Comment: Really not clear what you are asking and it seems more like a server side issue than an angular one

Comment: How is it a server side issue if I'm talking about the request the server receives? I can't make things more clear... please read again more carefully.

Comment: @Nathan  please give us more complete code so we can see where your issue is coming from.  The two lines of code that you have in your question don't give enough information

Comment: That's all that's in the resource factory. Beyond that I'm just using a resource instance and calling `$update()` on him. Are you asking to see the resource data object?

Comment: @Nathan what's your backend ?

Comment: Rails 4.1 with strong params

Comment: Downvoter... comment please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add properties to $resource object like

```
currentProduct.category_ids = [1,2,3];
```

Now this property becomes request parameter for PUT request.

Lets suppose you have $resource factory name "**Product**" then following code will work for you

```
  var currentProduct = new Product()

    // Bind properties to resource object
    currentProduct.id = 1
    currentProduct.description = 'Yada yada'
    currentProduct.category_ids =  [1,2,3]  

    // Initiate PUT request.
    currentProduct.$update()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe Rails expecting put request to follow pattern

> /product/:id

so when you want to update product you should call it

```
  product.$update({id:product.id});
```

and that will make request to url

```
http://api/v1/products?id=1
```

with request payload like

```
{"id":"1","description":"Yada yada","category_ids":[1,2,3]}
```

please see demo here

http://plnkr.co/edit/Utjoj6LirxvzMGSwoffo?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

We would need the code of that `$update` method, but I suspect it is relying on the `this` keyword, which is different depending on which object you are calling the function *from*.

Could you please try this and let us know if it works:

```
currentProduct.$update.bind(Product) ();
```

If it does, this means that indeed `$update` expect `this` to be `Product` (which is not the case and is `currentProduct` in your example instead).

Comment: I just update the code sample to show you what's in the resource factory. There is no other code. I'm just using the bare-bones angular 1.3 resource object with the exception of adding a bare-bones custom update method. This method can be called on the class like so: `Product.current(id: instance.id, product: instance)` or the instance like so: `instance.$current()`. My problem is the data sent to the server is different in both cases even when I'm dealing with the same instance.

Comment: Could you try my snippet and tell if it works? Also, how do you create `currentProduct` ? How does it have access to `$update` ?

Comment: It makes a `GET` call using the your snippet?

Comment: You say `Product.update(id: currentProduct.id, product: currentProduct)` works but `currentProduct.$update()` doesn't work. I say instead of these try `currentProduct.$update.bind(Product) ();`

Comment: Yes, I tried that, and I said it makes a `GET` call to the server rather than an `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a angular service

```
// Angular Service
angular.module('myApp').factory('Product', function($resource,ENV) 
  return $resource(ENV.apiEndpoint+'/api/v1/products/:id', {}, {        
    update: { method: 'PUT' , params:{id:'@id'}}        
  });
});
```

In your controller you have to set product object

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('ProductController', 
function ($scope,Product) {

  var requestParams = {
         id: 1,   //Service extracts this parameter to form the url         
         product: { 
            id: 1, 
            description: 'Yada yada' 
            category_ids: [1,2,3]
          }    
  }
   Product.update(requestParams,function(success){
               console.log(success)
        },function(error){
            console.log(error)});       
});
```